# Dynamically change the row layout of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm working on a chat module in an app, where I want the messages from two participants on opposing alignment (other user left-aligned and my own msg right-aligned). Right now, my row layout is passed in through a static layout xml (with msg and avatar left-aligned). Is there a way to modify the view dynamically, or is there a way to pass an alternative row layout for the UI system to pick at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that inside the `getView()` method of your *ArrayAdapter* class (assuming you are defining your own `ArrayAdapter`).

You could have something like this:

```
private class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
        private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    YourAdapter(YourListActivity activity) {
        super(mContext, 0);
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Inflate your view
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.avatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
            mViewHolder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Message message = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        // etc. Manipulate your views as you wish


        return convertView;
    }
}


   private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView message;
        ImageView avatar;
   }
```

`getView` will get called each time you the `ListView` is modified (like when you scroll or when new elements are added to it), so you can manipulate each row
 as you want there. 
Don't forget to set the array adapter of the `ListView` to an instance of this class.

```
listView.setListAdapter(new mYourAdapter);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;
ArrayList<String> s= new ArrayList<String>();
int time;
String names[]={"raghu","pavan","rakesh","raghu","pavan"};
Context c;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if((position%2)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;       
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

public Customlistadapter(CustomListView customListView, int time) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        s.add("Raghu");
    }
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(customListView);  
    c=customListView;
    this.time=time;
}
public int getCount() {
    return s.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return s.get(arg0);
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
return 0;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(CustomListView.chk==true)
    {
    s.add("Raghu"); 
    }
    else if(CustomListView.chk==false)
    {
    s.remove(s.size()-1);
    }       
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
    super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ViewHolder vh;
    vh= new ViewHolder();
    int type = getItemViewType(arg0);
    System.out.println("getView " + arg0  + " type = "+type);
    if(arg1==null )
    {
         switch (type) {
         case TYPE_ITEM1:
             arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, arg2,false);             
            vh.tv= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            vh.tv1= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            vh.tv2=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            vh.tv.setText(s.get(arg0));
            vh.tv1.setText(s.get(arg0));
            vh.tv2.setText(Integer.toString(time));
             break;
         case TYPE_ITEM2:
             arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewimg, arg2,false);
            vh= new ViewHolder();
            vh.iv1= (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            vh.iv2= (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.iv2);
            vh.iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            vh.iv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             break;
     }
        arg1.setTag(vh);
    }
    else
    {
        vh= (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
    }
    return arg1;
}
```

1.Your Cusom Adapter class extends base Adapter.
2. Override  getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount()
3. Inflate a view depending on the type in getView()

Answer (score 2):

A way I have been shown to do it (im not sure if its best practice or not!) is to have both views in one XML file.  At run time you can get a reference to each view (using findViewById) and set the visible property to gone of the one you dont want.

Ill try and find some sample code if thats not clear?

Comment: oh, that's doable? I ended up doing a custom simplecursoradapter, where i passed in an int[][] instead of int[] for the array of view IDs as I have been using simplecursoradapter before.

Answer (score -1):

My code:

```
private void setAlignment(ViewHolder holder, boolean isOutgoing, QBChatMessage chatMessage) {

    if (!isOutgoing) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        if (holder.txtMessage != null) {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubblevioletcopy);
            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            holder.lnr_image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } else {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    } else {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        if (holder.txtMessage != null) {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubblegraycopy);
            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } else {
            holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to your code.

Comment: i work on chat module when i send message then different layout or change the view and another person send me message then display different design