# Custom ListView with different row layouts to be inflated depending on webservice response

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListView.

I have 3 sets of views:

1. Imageview
2. VideoView
3. Textview.

I have a webserver which returns images, videos and texts. So based on the response from the server i would like to inflate the views for the row's in listview.

I am aware of inflating a custom layout using a custom adapter.

I would like to know how to inflate views types using a custom adapter?.

**For example :**

If the webserver returns image, inflate imageview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068423/dynamically-change-the-row-layout-of-a-listview/12275096#12275096. Here we can find inflating 2 different layouts Image and TextView.

Comment: i edited the question but i asked this question a long time back. i don't have the code. So i tried my best to improve the post and prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate each webservice response with ID 0-for Images, 1-for Texts and 2-for Videos. Store ID in a ArrayList. Then Override getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount(). Inflate appropriate views in getView().

```
   @Override

    public int getItemViewType(int position) 

    {

    int type;

    if (ID.get(position)== 0){
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;  //type 0 for image
    } else if (ID.get(position) == 1){
        type = TYPE_ITEM2; //type 1 for text
    }else {
        type = TYPE_ITEM3; //type 2 for videos
    }
    return type;
    }
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;    //three different layouts to be inflated
}
```