# getItemViewType() Shows error while using to dsiplay Image and Text on a ListView in different rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to create a ListView for a chat application in Android , In the listview I want to show Text layout if user type a text and Image Layout if user sends a image , I have designed two layouts as sms_row.xml  and sms_chat_row.xml , the app works fine if I use just Text and Just Image only , by making my condition manually true and false , but If i am trying to do that dynamically getItemViewType(int position) shows error and Image crashed , here is my code of Adapter class -->

**DevAdapter.java**

```
    package com.example.imageinsertdynamic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class DevAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Message> list;
    private Context mCont;
    LayoutParams lp;
    public Message ob;
    int type;

    public DevAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> msg) {
        super();
        this.mCont = context;
        this.list = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

 @Override
     public int getViewTypeCount() {
         return 2;
     }

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if(true)//if ob.issetStatus() true if user types and image if user selects an image from the directory. but getting nullPointerException here.
     {
     return 0; 
     }
     else
     {
   return 1;
     } 
 }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ob=(Message) this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        type=getItemViewType(position);//1 for case one and 2 for case 2 , need getItemViewtype() to bring this 1 and 2 but app crashes doing so need help in this function only

        /*
         * 
         * ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         * 
         * HHHHHHHHEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPPP HERE !!
         * 
         * 
         * \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
         */

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case 0:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mCont).inflate(R.layout.sms_row_chat, parent, false);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            break;
            case 1:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mCont).inflate(R.layout.sms_row, parent, false);
            holder.message = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        break;

            }
            }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        switch(type){
        case 0:
        holder.text.setText(ob.getmsg());
        System.out.println("value of isStatus image or text-->");
        lp = (LayoutParams) holder.text.getLayoutParams();
        break;
        case 1:
            holder.message.setImageBitmap(ob.getMessage());
            System.out.println("value of isStatus image or text-->");
            lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();
            break;

        }
        //Check whether message is mine to show green background and align to right
            if(ob.isMine())
            {  switch(type){
            case 0:
                holder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            break;
            case 1:
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                break;
            }
            }
            //If not mine then it is from sender to show orange background and align to left
            else
            {
                 switch(type){
                    case 0:
                holder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                break;
                    case 1:
                        holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                       break;
                 }
                 }
             switch(type){
                case 0:
            holder.text.setLayoutParams(lp);
            break;
                case 1:
                    holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    break;
             }
            //holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor);   

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {

        ImageView message;
        TextView text;
    }




    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have changed the return to 0 and 1 , but at the if Statement in getItemViewType(int position)
i have , the ob object is defined in getView so cant use it in getItemView(int position) what to do here to make it properly working ?

```
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         if(ob.isStatusMessage)//if ob.issetStatus() true if user types and image if user selects an image from the directory. but getting nullPointerException here.
         {
         return 0; 
         }
         else
         {
       return 1;
         } 
     }
```

isStatusMessage is from -->
**Message.java**

```
package com.example.imageinsertdynamic;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Message {
    /**
     * The content of the message
     */
    Bitmap message;
    String msg;
    /**
     * boolean to determine, who is sender of this message
     */
    boolean isMine;
    /**
     * boolean to determine, whether the message is a status message or not.
     * it reflects the changes/updates about the sender is writing, have entered text etc
     */
    boolean isStatusMessage;

    /**
     * Constructor to make a Message object
     */
    public Message(Bitmap message, boolean isMine,boolean status) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.isMine = isMine;
        this.isStatusMessage = status;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor to make a status Message object
     * consider the parameters are swaped from default Message constructor,
     *  not a good approach but have to go with it.
     */
    public Message(boolean status, String message,boolean isMine) {
        super();
        this.msg = message;
        this.isMine = isMine;
        this.isStatusMessage = status;
    }
    public Bitmap getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(Bitmap message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getmsg() {
        return msg;
    }
    public void setMessage(String text) {
        this.msg = text;
    }


    public boolean isMine() {
        return isMine;
    }
    public void setMine(boolean isMine) {
        this.isMine = isMine;
    }
    public boolean isStatusMessage() {
        return isStatusMessage;
    }
    public void setStatusMessage(boolean isStatusMessage) {
        this.isStatusMessage = isStatusMessage;
    }


}
```

Comment: You can add text and image components into a listview component. Which one you need, set it is visibility true and assign the value.

Comment: What error have You observed from getItemViewType(int position) ? And how do You change it 'dynamically'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337331/custom-listview-with-different-row-layouts-to-be-inflated-depending-on-webservic. might help

Comment: @sandrstar I am setting type=getItemViewType(position) in getView method but getting null pointerException error bu doing that way, I have a isstatusmessage in messsage.java class which check if its a text or image , and set it true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of returning 1 and 2, returns 0 and 1. It is like the index for an Array. If you create an array of two position and try to access array[2] you will get ArrayIndexOutBoundException. That's nearly what is happening to you

```
@Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if(true)//if ob.issetStatus() true if user types and image if user selects an image from the directory. but getting nullPointerException here.
     {
       return 0; 
     }
     else
     {
       return 1;
     }
```

Edit:

Tipically the condiotion is associated with the dataset (`ArrayList<Message>`). getItemViewType has as paramter the position. So you have to retrieve the item at that position, and check if the condition is met

Comment: this also doesnt helped , it still showed nullpointerexception , i am using int type=getItemView(position) inside getView method , type is in switch(type) which selects the case , manually keeping it 1 , and 2 is providing the desired result. What can i do ?

Comment: do you changed the case constants inside getView or you do keep it as before (1 and 2)?

Comment: duuhhh i think i should not be a programmer anymore , feel like killing myself , Thanks a lot now it works , but how can i put the if statement true false dynamically ? what to put there , you were great help

Comment: can you rephrease the last one ? What does mean "if statement true false dinamically" mean?

Comment: the if statement in getItemViewType(int position) , has if(true) return 0;
else
return 1;
now i want the true to be true only if it is a text message and false if its a Image , but my ob=(Message) new getItem(position) is the ob a object of Message type , i want ob.isStatusMessage which return true and false if its a image and text, how to use it in getitemViewType if it is initialized in getView ?

Comment: that's up to you. Tipically I associated this information with the dataset ArrayList<Message>

Comment: please check the edited comment , i have defined a function isstatusMessage() which return true if it is text and false if its image , how to use this function in getItemViewtype() if the object is instatiated in getView as ob=(Message) getItem(position) ? when using ob.isStatusMessage in if condition it says NullPointerException thats obvious as the object is defined in getView ? any help ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32414/discussion-between-divyanshunegi-and-blackbelt)